# DRY principle for useState in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, dry

I am learning react and trying to wrap around my head on the best practices for creating multiple useStates that essentially do the same thing except for different items in my code.

For example, my code is the follow:

```
import { Button, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { Box } from '@mui/system';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

export default MenuPage(){
  
   const menuItems = [
    {
        name: 'Americano',
        price: 1.50,
    },
    {
        name: 'Espresso',
        price: 3.50,
    },
    {
        name: 'Macchiato',
        price: 5.50,
    },
    {
        name: 'Cafe Mocha',
        price: 8.50,
    },
    {
        name: 'Latte',
        price: 6.50,
    },
    {
        name: 'Cappucino',
        price: 5.50,
    },
    {
        name: 'Frappe',
        price: 8.50,
    },
];

//*********************************************
// code that needs to be changed here instead of creaing n many useStates for n many items in menuItems list.

   const [order, setOrder] = useState('');

   const handleChange = (event) => {
    setOrder(event.target.value);
   };

//*********************************************

return(
     {menuItems.map((item) => {
            return (
                <Box display='flex' flexDirection='row' alignItems='center' justifyContent='center' textAlign='center' borderBottom='0.5px solid black' sx={{ my: 10, mx: 10 }}>
                    <Box flex={1} textAlign='center' sx={{ fontSize: '35px', }}>
                        {item.name}:
                    </Box>
                    <br />
                    <Box flex={1} textAlign='center' sx={{ fontSize: '25px' }}>
                        ${item.price}0
                    </Box>
                    <Box flex={0.5} textAlign='center'>
                        <FormControl fullWidth>
                            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Order</InputLabel>
                            <Select
                                value={order}
                                label="Order"
                                onChange={handleChange}>
                                <MenuItem value={1}>1</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={2}>2</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={3}>3</MenuItem>
                            </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Box>
                </Box>

            );
        })}

);
}
```

So my question is that instead of creating n many `const [nthOrder, setNthOrder] = useState('')` whats the best way to create as many useStates for each order ? I know we cannot run useState in a callBack or in forloops.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: May be in this scenario, you could add a prop named `order` to your `menuItems` array programmatically like so: `{menuItems.map(it => ({...it, order: ''})).map((item) => {`. Now, within the JSX for select: `<Select name={item.name} value={item.order}`. And, finally `handleChange` can use `event.target.name` to get the exact menuItem and update the order to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have several orders in the same state, you can set the state as array and add the order to the array.

```
   const [order, setOrder] = useState(['']);

   const handleChange = (event) => {
    setOrder(prevState => { return [...prevState, event.target.value]});
   };
```

In this example you can see that i use the spread operator to return a new array with the previous values plus the new value, that way you can avoid the repetition.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to maintain the `menuItems` as a state of the component. Add the `order` field to each menu item. Put the state and its CRUD logic into a custom hook, keep your component clean.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function useMenuItems() {
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState([
    { name: 'Americano', price: 1.5, order: '' },
    { name: 'Espresso', price: 3.5, order: '' },
    { name: 'Macchiato', price: 5.5, order: '' },
    { name: 'Cafe Mocha', price: 8.5, order: '' },
    { name: 'Latte', price: 6.5, order: '' },
    { name: 'Cappucino', price: 5.5, order: '' },
    { name: 'Frappe', price: 8.5, order: '' },
  ]);

  const setOrderForMenuItem = (nOrder, itemName) => {
    setMenuItems((pre) => {
      return pre.map((v) => (v.name === itemName ? { ...v, order: nOrder } : v));
    });
  };

  return { menuItems, setOrderForMenuItem } as const;
}

export default function MenuPage() {
  const { menuItems, setOrderForMenuItem } = useMenuItems();

  const handleChange = (event, item) => {
    setOrderForMenuItem(event.target.value, item.name);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {menuItems.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <select
            data-testid={`menu-order-${i}`}
            key={item.name}
            value={item.order}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, item)}
          >
            <option value={1}>1</option>
            <option value={2}>2</option>
            <option value={3}>3</option>
          </select>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```